# What is the name of this type of Android Studio popup windows or ideaVim action so i can navigate in it using IdeaVim?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, vim-plugin, ideavim

I want to be able to navigate in this kind of windows in Android Studio using IdeaVim. For that I need the name of propper action or the name of this type of popups so I can search further.

Examples of what I'm looking for:

[Example A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqTxh.png)

[Example B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQZWP.png)

I've already mapped navigation for this kind of auto-completion popups ([Example of what I'm NOT looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnpcf.png)),
but the mapping does not applies to the example A  & B above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out IdeaVim's readme. There is a chapter about executing IDE actions [https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#executing-ide-actions.\](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#executing-ide-actions.%5C)
So the actions you are looking for:
`map ?? <Action>(ShowIntentionActions)` - to open the intention actions
`map ?? <Action>(GoToAction)` - to open action search window
But at the moment IdeaVim works only in the editor, so you cant use `hjkl` to navigate in the windows above. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2347/Navigation-on-IDEA-windows-like-Settings-Switcher-etc

Comment: Thanks. What a shame that this feature is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The action id/name of your example 1 is `ShowIntentionActions` and `Show Context Menu`.

The action id/name of your example 2 is `GotoAction` and `Find Action`.

You could use the ways here to find any action id that you need for IdeaVIM: https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#finding-action-ids